# How to force symfony 2 assetic:dump save only concatenated file in web directory

Tags: symfony, twig

I already have all needed js files in web folder, when I use assetic:dump command it produces concatenated file and copies  all other files two the same directory. How can I avoid this?

code in twig template:

```
 {% block headerscripts %}
    {% javascripts output='assetic/vendors_header.js'
        'vendor/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'
        'vendor/html5shiv.js'
    %}
        <script src="{{ asset('assetic/vendors_header.js' ~ assets_version) }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: In `dev` or `prod` environments? Why don't you use [`{{ assets_url }}`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#combining-assets) with [`output`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#controlling-the-url-used)?

Comment: in dev environment. when i use "assets_url" i get all script separetly in browser instead o one compiled gifile.

Comment: IIRC that's the expected behaviour in dev environment: files are not concatenated in order to ease debugging.

Comment: If you want to force concatenation you can add `combine=true` to the javascripts tag.

Answer (score 0):

You added in a comment:

> in dev environment. when i use "assets_url" i get all script separetly in browser instead o one compiled gifile

That's the expected behaviour in `dev` environment: files are not concatenated in order to ease debugging.

> In the `dev` environment, each file is still served individually, so that you can debug problems more easily. However, in the `prod` environment (or more specifically, when the `debug` flag is `false`), this will be rendered as a single `script` tag, which contains the contents of all of the JavaScript files.

Source: [Symfony2 official documentation > How to Use Assetic for Asset Management> Combining Assets](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#combining-assets).