# Using Javascript vendors in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, package, composer-php

My Symfony2 project has a `composer.json` file which references the [CKEditor package](https://packagist.org/packages/ckeditor/ckeditor):

```
"require": {
    ...
    "ckeditor/ckeditor": "4.4.*"
},
```

When I include the main Javascript file in my Twig view:

```
{% javascripts
    '../vendor/ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js'
%}
    <script src="{{ asset(asset_url) }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

it renders a script path with the following URL:

```
http://myproject.local/app_dev.php/js/1c365ca_ckeditor_2.js"
```

This would be fine if it was a standalone Javascript file, but `ckeditor.js` is unable to reference its many other dependencies in the `vendor/ckeditor` directory. Even if I explicitly included them all with assetic, I'd be unable to update their relative paths so that they could be seen by ckeditor.

I'm sure this issue applies with all large Javascript libraries. How is this normally approached?

Comment: In `dev` environment, assetic won't merge Javascript files, see [How to force symfony 2 assetic:dump save only concatenated file in web directory](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28295905/2257664). Does this problem appears in `prod` environment?

Comment: Have you tried to use a [CKEditor bundle](https://github.com/egeloen/IvoryCKEditorBundle)?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem and I think assetic is not the best tool when dealing with third party standalone libraries, which are not integrated in bundles.

So I found a workaround by creating a symboling link to ckeditor vendor directory in the `web` directory of my symfony project:

```
cd web

ln -s ../vendor/ckeditor/ckeditor/ ./ckeditor
```

Then in my twig template I call the CKeditor script like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        // Change CKeditor basepath configuration
        CKEDITOR.basePath = "/ckeditor/";

        // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
        // instance, using default configuration.
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on the CKEditor bundle : [Github](https://github.com/egeloen/IvoryCKEditorBundle) - [Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/egeloen/ckeditor-bundle)

This bundle is an integration of CKEditor for Symfony.

You can insert CKEditor area in your form.